# Showing the non-pseudorandomness of a generator

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

I'm sorry if this question is too novice. It comes from a practice midterm in a cryptography course which I'm taking, and my confusion here is really that I don't know the "tools" that one uses in practice for this sort of question. The notation (and class) is Katz's.

I've been given a PRG $G(s)$; I'm trying to show explicitly that $s\mathbin\|G(s)$ is not a PRG. Intuitively, I'd expect both components to be random-seeming, so there's nothing obvious that sticks out to me to XOR or manipulate.

Comment: What's the probability that a uniform random string $s \mathbin\| x$ satisfies $G(s) = x$, assuming the lengths all work out?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage So, my distinguisher $D$ has "access" to the PRG $G$? (I'm sorry, that just wasn't very clear from the start to me.)

Comment: Yep!  The only thing it doesn't have _a priori_ is the original input to the putative generator $G'\colon s \mapsto s \mathbin\| G(s)$.  Of course, $G'$ just happens to cough it up in the output, so, _a posteriori_…

Comment: In particular, your goal is to write a decision algorithm $A$ such that $A(G'(s)) = A(s \mathbin\| G(s))$ and $A(u)$ have substantially different probability of returning 1, where $u$ and $s$ are uniform random strings of the appropriate lengths.

Comment: Incidentally, I know that the answer to your question is $\frac{2^n}{2^{2n}}$, since the subset of strings $r \in \{0,1\}^{2n}$ in this format is constrained by $G$ having a range of size $2^n$.

Comment: So if $A(s \mathbin\| x)$ returns 1 when $G(s) = x$ and 0 when $G(s) \ne x$, what's $\Pr[A(s \mathbin\| G(s))]$ and what's $\Pr[A(u)]$?  And finally, what's the formal definition of the PRG distinguisher advantage?

Answer (score 1):

This is an attempt to answer my own question based on Squeamish's helpful comments. If terminology is unclear or misleading, *please* tell me!

Let $D(s) = \mathbb{I}\{s = x||G(x), x \in \{0,1\}^n\}$. Then, if our putative PRG is $G'$, $\Pr[D(G'(s)) = 1] = 1$ - that is, $G'(s)$ is always in the format that $D$ looks for. However, $\Pr[D(r) = 1]$ (where $r$ is uniform from $\{0,1\}^{2n}$) is $\frac{2^n}{2^{2n}}$, to reflect that $s||G(s)$ has a range of only $2^n$ - being completely determined by $s$ - while there are $2^{2n}$ possible values $r$.

Thus $|\Pr[D(G'(s)) = 1] - \Pr[D(r) = 1]| = 1 - \frac{2^n}{2^{2n}}$, a non-negligible function.